# How to clone or copy a Jena-Ontology-Model (OntModel) to apply temporary changes?

Tags: validation, sparql, jena, ontology, protege

I've been searching for a solution for days now and since there is no forum at Apache Jena I had to create an account at stackoverflow to ask.
My problem is that I need a temporary (deep) copy of an already loaded ontology, namely an object of `OntModelImpl` (with some imports but without any attached inference machine). Its purpose is to apply some validation steps on the model which require some SPARQL UPDATE queries to add some automatically generated triples first. These additional triples are only intended for the validation and should not find their way into the original model!
There is no copy- or clone-method on the object itself and through my many searches I couldn’t find any static (?) methods anywhere else to fulfil this purpose. Instead there is some kind of "copy constructor" (not really marked as such) on `OntModelImpl` which takes a specification (`OntModelSpec`) and a `Model`. I tried to use it this way:

```
workingModel = new OntModelImpl(ontModel.getSpecification(), ontModel);
```

Where `ontModel` is an `OntModelImpl` which was previously created through a call of `JenaOWLModel.getOntModel()`. The `JenaOWLModel` itself is part of the Protégé-3-API and was created through a call to `OwlProjectFromReaderCreator.getOwlModel()`. This creator (together with a necessary repository) was used to load the original ontology with its imports. `workingModel` denotes my working copy I am trying to create.
The initial problem with the shown code line was that it throws multiple `DoesNotExistException`s, a dozen or more call levels beneath. These denote that the import ontologies couldn't be found??? As I mentioned before, the original model is already loaded, inclusive all imports. (I skip some details here to shorten the story.)
Later I found out that I can suppress the exceptions by setting

```
ontModel.getSpecification().getDocumentManager().setProcessImports(false);
```

before the constructor-call. From this point everything looked fine, no exceptions anymore, I got two different model objects with the same triple counts in their different graphs (I did a quick compare of the object IDs of all first and second level attributes of the two instances of `OntModelImpl` to make sure it is a deep copy). But today I got aware of something strange: There is no problem when adding the validation triples the first time - I write the triple count to stdout before and after the SPARQL-UPDATE-INSERT-requests. But when I call the validation for the second time, the original model **does already contain the additional triples**!?
That means either the two models are linked somehow I couldn't see or Jena uses some kind of global linking-, maybe caching-mechanism I am not aware of which tries to hold all models with the same URI consistent to each other or something totally different.
So I really need help here! How can I get a copy of an `OntModel` (`OntModelImpl`) to apply temporary changes which I want to throw away afterwards?

Greetings and thanks for your time

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking here, but since you mentioned "no forum at Apache jena ",it's worth pointing out that there is a pretty responsive users' mailing list.

Comment: Yes, I've read about the support list, but I don't like this kind of "closed communication" (I've read that it's published afterwards.) in this context. They also point out the "curated collections of Jena questions on StackOverflow" and so I came here. Also Google brought me here for every question I had in the past - and never to the Jena-Mail-Archives I just saw today for the first time (Is it not indexed by Google?). - So, since

Comment: I came here many times to read about other people's questions and answers (not only for Jena, I admit) I thought others would too.

Comment: Yes, as I said, there's nothing the matter with asking here;  it's a good place to ask.  I was just correcting the mistaken impression that "there is no forum at Apache Jena".

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @dr0i did not work for me.

This worked:
`Model copy = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().add(originalModel);`

`ModelFactory` creates `Model` subclasses as well: `createInfModel()`, `createOntologyModel()`.

I tested with the following logic.

```
int size = originalModel.size();
Model copy = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().add(originalModel);
copy.removeAll();
assert originalModel.size() == size;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not working on ontologies right now (nearly three years later) but I've seen that your shown logic does not proof to have created a deep copy at all (only that the "copy" did not only reference the original). - Have you verified this?
You should at least call 'removeAll()' on the original and then compare its old size with the size of the copy. This should show the same size of the two models.

Comment: Yes, the comparison works the other way as well: `originalModel.removeAll()` does not affect the `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

How to make a deep copy of the `Model`:

```
Model copyOfOntModel = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(ontModel.getGraph());
```

Then use this to instantiate your new `OntModelImpl`:

```
workingModel = new OntModelImpl(ontModel.getSpecification(),copyOfOntModel);
```