# How to clone a JENA OntModel to another with a different ModelSpec

Tags: owl, jena, ontology

I have an OntModel in Jena with an OWL_MEM_RDFS_INF ModelSpec. However I created a utility to count the number of individuals, properties, etc... in the model. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645110/method-listindividual-takes-more-than-15-mins-with-dbpedia-2014-owl-2mb-siz) it takes forever to execute the `model.listIndividuals()` method which is normal because I am using some reasoning abilities.

It's further demonstrated because if I use the basic OWL_MEM ModelSpec I don't have any problem.

I tried to clone the model graph and use another ModelSpec by using what's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713884/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-jena-ontology-model-ontmodel-to-apply-temporary-changes):

```
  Model copyOfOntModel = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(model.getGraph());
  OntModel newModel = new OntModelImpl(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, copyOfOntModel);
```

But it still takes forever when I execute the `model.listIndividuals()` method. Is there a way to clone the model but use the basic ModelSpec for example?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but `OntModel` would have the method [getRawModel()](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/InfModel.html#getRawModel--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied what UniformedUser said, but as as the result of the `getRawModel()` method is not an `OntModel`, I just did:

```
  Model _model = model.getRawModel();
  OntModel newModel = new OntModelImpl(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, _model);
```

And it just works!!